# Error while detecting Seasonality in a Time Series Analysis using seasonal_decompose

Tags: python, time-series

[I have been geting this error message when trying to detect seasonality ]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G5i2.png)

Error Message: C:\Users\Tanul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\converter.py:256: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
base = dates.epoch2num(dt.asi8 / 1.0e9)

The output graph doesn't show any pattern from the input data.

Kindly suggest!

Comment: What is inside `df.market_value`? What is the type of its index? Can you share a part of it?

Comment: I am still stuck at EDA while doing TSA, will connect with you on Seasonality once it appears again.

Comment: In the meanwhile, can you address another query:

I am attempting to assign frequency to the Date columns, daily time stamp. I am trying to asfreq based on business days for the data

Command line : df= df.asfreq(freq='b'). 

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks!